# Using angular how to convert number to Indian currency word format with paise (decimal value)

Tags: angular

I am trying to reflect total amount with decimal values in words, but the problem is its shows only integer part. Can anyone suggest how to show those decimal numbers in word(or in paisa).

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipe `currency`  `<div>{{ money | currency:'INR':true }}</div>`

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-pipe-format

More reference about currency pipe at https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe